# How to pass method arguments to an ActionListener?

Tags: jsf-2, el

I'm creating a dynamically generated menu. In the database, I have stored the directory (`String`) of each submenu and stored in an `ArrayList` in the bean. This is a part of the code:

```
<c:forEach items="#{controlWeb.algorithms}" var="alg">
    <h:form>
        <h:commandLink actionListener="#{controlWeb.setContent(PROBLEM)}"  value="About"/>
    </h:form>
</c:forEach>
```

The problem is in "PROBLEM". I want to write `#{alg.algorithm1}` and it doesn't work because I think it isn't posible to nest EL expressions.

The `actionListener` set the `String` `#{alg.algorithm1}` in another `String`. How can I achieve the requirement?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `action`, not `actionListener`. The `actionListener` must be bound to a method which takes `ActionEvent` as the sole argument, no excuses. Also, an `actionListener` isn't intented to *invoke* actions, but to *listen* on actions (so that you can log it or do some preprocessing task or whatever).

```
<c:forEach items="#{controlWeb.algorithms}" var="alg">
    <h:form>
        <h:commandLink action="#{controlWeb.setContent(alg.algorithm)}" value="About"/>
    </h:form>
</c:forEach>
```

Note that passing arguments in EL is only supported since EL 2.2 which is shipped along Servlet 3.0 / Java EE 6. You need to make sure that you're targeting a Servlet 3.0 compatible container with a Servlet 3.0 compatible `web.xml`.

#### See also:

- [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener)
- [How to call a method with a parameter in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273729/how-to-call-a-method-with-a-parameter-in-jsf/5273864#5273864)

Comment: Thank You so much again BalusC thanks to you im learning JSF so fastly.