# how to get mapping id dynamically from data base

Tags: mysql, jsf, jsf-2, prettyfaces

i am developing an application in which i have put menus which are rendered from mysql database i have inserted menus names and mappingIds into db table.
now i am getting problem how do i rendered list (list of menus) into xhtml(jsf html tags) currently i am using this
i have saved all menus in `subMenuBeanList` and stored this list into `Session`
and then iterate(`ui:repeat`) `subMenuBeanList` into xhtml file where i want to get menus names(show menus names to the user) like this: `h:commandLink value="#{subMenuBeanList.subMenuNameBean}"` and mappingId `action="#{subMenuBeanList.subMenuLinkBean}"` see clear code below :

```
 <ui:repeat value="#{session.getAttribute('subMenuBeanList')}" var="subMenuBeanList">

<h:commandLink value="#{subMenuBeanList.subMenuNameBean}"   action="#{subMenuBeanList.subMenuLinkBean}" />  
// i want this <h:commandLink value="menu One Name" action="pretty:menuonemappingid" />
//<h:commandLink value="menu Two Name" action="pretty:menutwomappingid" />
// so on depending upon records in table
// closing tags
```

here when i click on `h:commandLink` i get this Exception

```
javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /template/templateslider.xhtml @56,123 action="#{subMenuBeanList.subMenuLinkBean}": Method not found: com.hesco.repository.common.generalinformation.managed.bean.SubMenuBean@1a0974ce.subMenuLinkBean()
```

i know this `subMenuLinkBean` is not a method its a variable in action(.java) class but here i put it into `action="#{subMenuBeanList.subMenuLinkBean}"` thats why i am getting this exception..

my question is that how do i do this ? i want to get mappingId from Db not hard coded in any file

**this is managed bean class**

```
@ManagedBean(name="subMenuBean")
@ViewScoped
public class SubMenuBean implements Serializable {



    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Integer subMenuIdBean;
    private Integer menuIdBean;
    private String subMenuNameBean;
    private String subMenuLinkBean;
    private String isActive;
    //jsf will not create nasted object, so that i create it like this.
    private MenuBean menuBean = new MenuBean();

    //private Set<Assigneduserrole> assigneduserroles = new HashSet<Assigneduserrole>(0);
    private ArrayList<SubMenuBean> subMenuBeanList = null;

///setter and getter
```

**this is an other class from where i am setting beans value**
`query` is fatched db records..

```
for (Iterator it = query.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                                    Object[] obj = (Object[]) it.next();

                                    log.info("assigning role by iterator");
                                    // adding Section Beans into ArrayList

                                    SubMenuBean subMenuBean = new SubMenuBean();
                                    subMenuBean.setSubMenuIdBean(((Submenu) obj[2]).getSubMenuId());
                                    subMenuBean.setSubMenuNameBean(((Submenu) obj[2]).getSubMenuName());
                                    subMenuBean.setSubMenuLinkBean(((Submenu) obj[2]).getSubMenuLink());
                                    subMenuBean.setMenuIdBean(((Submenu) obj[2]).getMenu().getMenuId());
                                    subMenuBean.setIsActive(((Submenu) obj[2]).getIsActive());
                                    this.subMenuBeanList.add(subMenuBean);

                                    log.info("Sub Menu List: " + this.subMenuBeanList.size());

                                } // ending of Object iterator
```

Comment: How to do what? You know that what you describe is not valid, but I don´t understand what you are really trying to do (what are the links supposed to do?)

Comment: i have updated question see code section

Comment: Can you post your managed bean code

Comment: i haved updated my question

Comment: Is there a problem if you send your mappingid as a parameter in the call/method?

Comment: @danRod how ?i can't understand that

Comment: I don't know wich specific JSF2.x are you using but this [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083491/how-to-pass-method-arguments-to-an-actionlistener), [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401771/passing-parameter-to-jsf-action) and [link3](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/4-ways-to-pass-parameter-from-jsf-page-to-backing-bean/) maybe help you to understand

Comment: using `jsf 2.1, prettyfaces 3.3.3, primefaces 3.5 , hibernate 4.0`