# Command button with EL method argument does not invoke action method

Tags: jsf, datatable, facelets

I am trying to delete a database entry by sending the primary key "userId" as EL method argument via a command button to my managed bean.

My current code looks like

Bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class HibernateUserHandling 
{
...
public void deleteUser(String userIdViaXhtml)
{
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    session.createQuery("DELETE FROM AddressDetails WHERE USERID = :userIdViaXhtml");
    session.createQuery("DELETE FROM UserDetails WHERE USERID = :userIdViaXhtml");

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}
...
}
```

View:

```
    <html>
    <body>
        <ui:composition template="./generalTemplate.xhtml"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="cssHibernate.css" />
                <h:form id="main">
                    <h:dataTable value="#{hibernateDataOutput.persons}" var="list"
                                styleClass="order-table"
                                headerClass="order-table-header"
                                rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row">
                        ...
                            <f:facet name="header">Delete</f:facet>
                            <h:commandButton id="userId" action="#{hibernateUserHandling['deleteUser(list.userId)']}" image="delete.jpg" />
                        </h:column>
                    </h:dataTable>
                    ...
                </h:form>
            </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tested more ways, e.g. via getting the value to a seperate variable in the bean like in a inputText, but nothing worked.

I think I got a totally wrong basic approach.

I get the following error:

```
/hibernate.xhtml @39,137 action="#{hibernateUserHandling.deleteUser(list.userId)}" Failed to parse the expression [#{hibernateUserHandling.deleteUser(list.userId)}]
```

Stack trace:

```
    javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException: /hibernate.xhtml @39,137 action="#{hibernateUserHandling.deleteUser(list.userId)}" Failed to parse the expression [#{hibernateUserHandling.deleteUser(list.userId)}]
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getMethodExpression(TagAttributeImpl.java:232)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ActionSourceRule$ActionMapper2.applyMetadata(ActionSourceRule.java:104)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.MetadataImpl.applyMetadata(MetadataImpl.java:81)
            at javax.faces.view.facelets.MetaTagHandler.setAttributes(MetaTagHandler.java:129)
            at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.setAttributes(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:102)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.doNewComponentActions(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:402)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:159)
            at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
            at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
            at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:188)
            at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
            at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
            at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:188)
            at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
            at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
            at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:188)
            at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
            at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:103)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:178)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:395)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:366)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:108)
            at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:188)
            at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
            at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
            at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:188)
            at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
            at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
            at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:86)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:308)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:367)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:346)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:155)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:86)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:152)
            at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:769)
            at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:100)
            at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
            at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
            at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:410)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:877)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:594)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1675)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
    Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [#{hibernateUserHandling.deleteUser(list.userId)}]
            at org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createNodeInternal(ExpressionBuilder.java:146)
            at org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.build(ExpressionBuilder.java:172)
            at org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createMethodExpression(ExpressionBuilder.java:223)
            at org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.createMethodExpression(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:57)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getMethodExpression(TagAttributeImpl.java:222)
            ... 61 more
    Caused by: org.apache.el.parser.ParseException: Encountered " "(" "( "" at line 1, column 35.
    Was expecting one of:
        "}" ...
        "." ...
        "[" ...
        ">" ...
        "gt" ...
        "<" ...
        "lt" ...
        ">=" ...
        "ge" ...
        "<=" ...
        "le" ...
        "==" ...
        "eq" ...
        "!=" ...
        "ne" ...
        "&&" ...
        "and" ...
        "||" ...
        "or" ...
        "*" ...
        "+" ...
        "-" ...
        "/" ...
        "div" ...
        "%" ...
        "mod" ...

            at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.generateParseException(ELParser.java:2142)
            at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.jj_consume_token(ELParser.java:2024)
            at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.DeferredExpression(ELParser.java:113)
            at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.CompositeExpression(ELParser.java:40)
            at org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createNodeInternal(ExpressionBuilder.java:114)
            ... 65 more
```

Comment: I don't use Hibernate, but from jpa background: You create a query but you never fire it. And you don't set your parameter. Or did you omit some (important) lines?

Comment: As that classes are kinda long I have broken down the code to the important Classes/Lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Facelet composition is wrong. Anything outside `<ui:composition>` is ignored in final view and the template client content needs to go inside `<ui:define>`. You have the `<h:form>` *outside* the template definition `<ui:define>`, so it is not included in the final view and hence the buttons don't have any form to submit and they just won't seem to work at all.

Rearrange your Facelet template client as follows:

```
<ui:composition template="./generalTemplate.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="cssHibernate.css" />
        <h:form id="main">
            <h:dataTable value="#{hibernateDataOutput.persons}" var="list"
                         styleClass="order-table"
                         headerClass="order-table-header"
                         rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Delete</f:facet>
                    <h:commandButton id="userId" action="#{hibernateUserHandling.deleteUser(list.userId)}" image="delete.jpg" />
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

#### See also:

- [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked)
- [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets/4793959#4793959)

---

**Unrelated** to your concrete problem, the Hibernate code is flawed. But that's subject to a different question.

---

**Update**: as per the stacktrace which you edited afterwards in the question,

```
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [#{hibernateUserHandling.deleteUser(list.userId)}]
```

Apparently your environment does not support EL 2.2 at all. You need to make sure that the `web.xml` is declared conform Servlet 3.0 API and that you're deploying to a Servlet 3.0 compatible servlet container (e.g. Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, JBoss AS 6, etc).

#### See also:

- [How to call a method with a parameter in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273729/how-to-call-a-method-with-a-parameter-in-jsf/5273864#5273864)

Answer (score 0):

hibernate code is not correct.
Modify your method as

```
public void deleteUser(String userIdViaXhtml)
{
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    Query query = session.createQuery("DELETE FROM AddressDetails WHERE USERID = :userIdViaXhtml");
    query.setString("userIdViaXhtml",userIdViaXhtml);
    query.executeUpdate();

    session.createQuery("DELETE FROM UserDetails WHERE USERID = :userIdViaXhtml");
    query.setString("userIdViaXhtml",userIdViaXhtml);
    query.executeUpdate();

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}
```

Tip: handle exceptions for proper rollback and dont write this code directly in JSF managed bean make use of DAO pattern.

1. [DAO @ Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object)
2. [J2EE DAO Pattern](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/DataAccessObject.html)

Comment: Thank you, but I got a little different error I edited now to the topic