# How to pass an argument to method from rendered h:outputText?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, el, ajax4jsf

I am displaying a table of data from an sql query and want to render a section of code based on one of the field values from this sql query.

View: records.xthml

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>#{messages['table.header.id']}</td>
      <td>#{messages['table.header.name']}</td>
      <td>#{messages['table.header.date.added']}</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <a4j:repeat value="recordListBean.records" var="listedRecord" rowKeyVar="index">
      <tr>
        <td><h:outputText value="#{listedRecord.id}</td>
        <td><h:outputText value="#{listedRecord.name}</td>
        <td>
          <h:outputText value="#{listedRecord.dateAdded}" rendered="#{viewRecordBean.currentRecord(listedRecord.id)}" />
          <h:outputText value="#{messages['table.header.record.archived']}" rendered="!#{viewRecordBean.currentRecord(listedRecord.id)}" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </a4j:repeat>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller: ViewListBean.java

```
public boolean currentRecord(Long recordId) {
  Long maxRecordId = 10;
  if (recordId <= maxRecordId) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

The two rows of records.xhtml code in question are:

```
<h:outputText value="#{listedRecord.candidate}" rendered="#{viewRecordBean.currentRecord(listedRecord.id)}" />
<h:outputText value="#{messages['table.header.record.archived']}" rendered="#{!viewRecordBean.currentRecord(listedRecord.id)}" />
```

I want to be able to pass an argument within the rendered check and return a boolean to render or not.  Let's say that there are 20 records returned in this sql query.  If the `recordId` value of the current row is less than or equal to 10, it will return true and the `listedRecord.dateAdded` field will be displayed.  Otherwise it will return false and the word `Archived` will be displayed.

Is this the correct way to pass an argument from a JSF generated XHTML page to the controlling bean's method?

Is there a better or more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: If I were you, I would do something like that:  `value="#{viewRecordBean.currentRecord(listedRecord.id) ? listedRecord.candidate : messages['table.header.record.archived']}" `. Instead of two lines you have only one and you check the condition only one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've only one mistake: the `!` has to go inside the EL expression.

I.e. this is invalid:

```
rendered="!#{viewRecordBean.currentRecord(listedRecord.id)}"
```

it should be:

```
rendered="#{!viewRecordBean.currentRecord(listedRecord.id)}"
```

For the remnant it look as it should work just fine, assuming that your environment supports EL 2.2. I'd only use a `<h:dataTable>` as that eliminates HTML boilerplate.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!!I'm quite the newbie to JSF/Java/EL, etc.  How do I tell what EL my stack supports?

Comment: Depends on server and web.xml version. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273729/how-to-call-a-method-with-a-parameter-in-jsf

Comment: It appears I am using jboss-el-2.0.1. with Mojarra.

Comment: For now, I need to keep the HTML boilerplate, so I still need to use the `a4j:repeat` option.  When I do this, the `listedRecord.id` refuses to come through to the `viewRecordBean.currentRecord(listedRecord.id)` method as anything but null.  I'm not sure how to get the actual value to come through.

Comment: My mistake... this is actually working. I've now been able to verify that the parameter value is actually being passed through correctly. Thanks again for your help!!