# Failed to parse the expression [#{contatosController.adicionar(actionEvent)}]

Tags: jsf, el

I'm trying to learn JSF and EL and I am facing the following error:

```
/index.xhtml @20,120 actionListener="#{contatosController.adicionar(actionEvent)}" Q
```

What does that mean and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It means that your environment does not support the EL 2.2 feature of invoking methods with arguments. The EL syntax `#{bean.method(argument)}` is unsupported in EL 2.1 and older and therefore unparsable. Just get rid of that argument. JSF fills it in by itself anyway.

```
actionListener="#{contatosController.adicionar}"
```

Please note that even if you upgraded to EL 2.2, it would still end up in trouble as you're essentially passing `null` to it (you don't have a managed bean `#{actionEvent}`, right?). You should actually never need to specify the default argument of a JSF (action)listener method yourself.

#### See also:

- [How to call a method with a parameter in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273729/how-to-call-a-method-with-a-parameter-in-jsf/5273864#5273864)
- [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener/3909382#3909382)