# How to pass argument in listener?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, arguments, listener, el

How can I pass an arugument to listener method?

I have tried like this:

```
<p:poll interval="3" listener="#{vehicleController.onPoll('12')}"
    update="vehicleDataList"/>
```

and

```
<p:poll interval="3" listener="#{vehicleController.onPoll(vehicle.vehicleLicense)}"
    update="vehicleDataList"/>
```

But it throws the following exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: /monitorVehicles/vehiclesList.xhtml
Failed to parse the expression [#{vehicleController.onPoll('12')}]
```

How can I achive this?

Comment: Already tried it. Its not working. listener is expecting a string.

Comment: can you show the signature of your listener ?

Comment: btw, what version of JSF are you using ?

Comment: Its String. jsf 2.1 am using.

Comment: Please elaborate "not working" in developer's terms instead of in enduser's terms. Do you get an error/exception? Or is `null` being passed? Or is the action not queued? Etc.

Comment: getting this exception "Failed to parse the expression [#{vehicleController.onPoll('12')}]"

Comment: Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: @TejaMaridu update your question with meaningful stacktrace

Comment: Thank you for your update. In the future, please do not ignore errors/exceptions as if they are decoration. They definitely are not. They are the whole answer at its own. You just have to *understand* it, or if you are unable to, post it here so that someone else can translate the exception/error in layman's terms.

Comment: ok i will from next time. Thanks for quick response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *getting this exception "Failed to parse the expression [#{vehicleController.onPoll('12')}]"*

Your environment doesn't support the new EL 2.2 feature of invoking methods with arguments.

EL 2.2 is part of Servlet 3.0, thus in order to utilize it, you need to deploy to a Servlet 3.0 compatible container (e.g. Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, JBoss AS 6, etc) with a Servlet 3.0 compatible `web.xml` file. If you don't deploy to a Servlet 3.0 compatible container, or don't have a Servlet 3.0 compatible `web.xml`, then you aren't using EL 2.2 at all and you will get this kind of exception.

If you're actually targeting/deploying to a Servlet 2.5 compatible container (and thus using EL 2.1), then you can use JBoss EL to have the new EL 2.2-like features in EL 2.1.

#### See also:

- [How to call a method with a parameter in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273729/how-to-call-a-method-with-a-parameter-in-jsf/5273864#5273864)
- [Invoke direct methods or methods with arguments / variables / parameters in EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284236/jsf-2-0-method-invocation/3284328#3284328)

Answer (score 1):

In **JSF 2**:

If your listener is expecting  a string:

```
"#{vehicleController.onPoll('11')}"

public void onPOll(String s){

}
```

If your listener is expecting an int:

```
"#{vehicleController.onPoll(11)}"
public void onPoll(int i){

}
```