# How to leverage EL 2.2 functionality on Weblogic 10.3.3

Tags: jquery, weblogic

I have been using tomcat 7 for local testing and when i deployed the code to weblogic0.3.3 version. ELexception occurred in JSP.

```
<c:forEach items="${command.map }" var="variable">
<c:set value="${command.function(value1, value2)}" />
```

I tried adding el-api-2.2.jar and el.impl-2.2.jar to WEB-INF/lib and then added the following to web.xml

```
<context-param>
          <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
          <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Then I added this entry to weblogic.xml

```
<container-descriptor>
<prefer-application-packages>
<package-name>com.sun.el.*</package-name>
<package-name>javax.el.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
</container-descriptor>
```

It still didn't work for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the exact error/stack trace?

Comment: Syntax error in expression. Encountered "(". Expected one of : "}", ".", "[", ">", "gt", "<", "lt", ">=", "ge", "<=", "le", "==", "eq", "!=", "ne", "&&", "and", "||", "or", "*", "+", "-", "?", "/", "div", "%", "mod",

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836525/org-apache-el-parser-parseexception-encountered-at-line-1-column-1 You should not have those jars in `WEB-INF` and you may still be using the wrong syntax